# Getting OauthException using Restfb latest version 1.9.0

Tags: java, restfb

We are using restfb latest version 1.9.0. After migrating the latest version am unable to fetch posts using public search.

How do I make the access token active.

> >
>   An active access token must be used to query information

I am getting the following error while running your code from github

```
run-reader-examples:
     [java] * Fetching single objects *30 Mar, 2015 6:51:05 PM com.restfb.DefaultWebRequestor execute
     [java] 
     [java] FINE: Making a GET request to https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=517312558337191%7C5oHY9T3cZICO_TCeK8OdXKg5Y08&format=json
     [java] 30 Mar, 2015 6:51:09 PM com.restfb.DefaultWebRequestor execute
     [java] FINE: Facebook responded with HTTP status code 400 and response body: {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
     [java] Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. (code 2500, subcode null)
     [java]     at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionForTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1189)
     [java]     at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1104)
     [java]     at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1038)
     [java]     at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:951)
     [java]     at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:914)
     [java]     at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.fetchObject(DefaultFacebookClient.java:415)
     [java]     at com.restfb.example.GraphReaderExample.fetchObject(GraphReaderExample.java:101)
     [java]     at com.restfb.example.GraphReaderExample.runEverything(GraphReaderExample.java:83)
     [java]     at com.restfb.example.GraphReaderExample.main(GraphReaderExample.java:75)
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get information from the `/me` endpoint using an app access token. You need a user or page access token.

Comment: Correct, but with a new user access token, how does one "make the access token active"? That is get information from the /me endpoint? Is it not via the FacebookClient object?